# Neural network in pytorch predict two binary variables

Tags: backpropagation, pytorch

Suppose I want to have the general neural network architecture:

```
                     ---> BinaryOutput_A
                    / 
Input --> nnLayer -
                    \
                     ---> BinaryOutput_B
```

An input is put through a neural network layer which then goes to predict two binary variables (i.e., `A` is `[0 or 1]` and `B` is `[0 or 1]`.

In pytorch, you can make such a network with:

```
class NN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, inputs):        
        super(NN, self).__init__()

        # -- first layer
        self.lin = nn.Linear(inputs,10)        

        # -- firstLayer --> binaryOutputA
        self.l2a = nn.Linear(10,2)

        # -- firstLayer --> binaryOutputB
        self.l2b = nn.Linear(10,2)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        o = self.lin(inputs)
        o1 = F.log_softmax(self.l2a(o))
        o2 = F.log_softmax(self.l2b(o))        
        return o1, o2
```

In my `train` function, I calculate the loss with `loss = loss_function(output, target)`.  If that's the case, to properly backpropagate the loss to both the `l2a` and `l2b` layers using `loss.backward()`, could I simply `concat` the `target` with the proper label for `l2a` and `l2b`?  In that sense, the output would be `[outputPredictionA, outputPredictionB]` and I could make the target be `[labelA, labelB]`, Would pytorch know to properly assign the loss to each layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that torch is actually really smart, and you can just calculate the total loss as:

```
loss = 0
loss += loss_function(pred_A, label_A)
loss += loss_function(pred_B, label_B)

loss.backward()
```

and the error will be properly backpropagated through the network.  No `torch.cat()` needed or anything.

Comment: That is true, but it is not because Pytorch is smart. Rather, it is a property of the derivative of addition.